# No way to delete own answer in Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: support, feature-request, answers, android-app

I cannot delete my answer from the Stack Exchange Android app. Is the feature missing or the feature is not present for some reasons?

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Allow us to vote to delete from the Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/allow-us-to-vote-to-delete-from-the-android-app)

Comment: Same problem. Just now posted an answer by mistake instead of comment and couldn't delete. I know it was careless on my part but just happened and would have loved a way to correct it by deleting.

Comment: @pussbee not a duplicate. This one is about deleting own answer. That one is to sure l allow to vote for deletion.

Comment: @AndroidMechanic Even when you're deleting you own post, you still cast a vote for deletion. It can be found on the /votes tab of your profile. If the vote is cast by the author of the question, it takes effect immediately (with some exceptions).

Comment: 3 years later, and this is still an issue. I just accidentally pressed "Add an answer" instead of "Add comment" (the buttons are right on top of each other) and didn't notice until my intended comment showed up as an answer. Had to find a desktop to correct it.

Comment: Another year gone by with no solution.

Comment: I think this is still an issue more than one year later

Answer (score 16):

I was about to do same question when I found yours. It is already been a year since your question and nothing as been done regards to this matter.

It is still impossible to delete an own answer in SE app, in IMHO this feature should be implemented ASAP.

By using the SE app, we can somehow answer a question by mistake or if we think after all our answer is wrong and there is ,at the moment, no way of deleting our own answer.

This could leads to a lot of unnecessary discussion in the comment section, trolling and etc, even serial down-voting.

Comment: Serial downvoting isn't a real problem, it will be corrected automatically. And the person who is doing so is *abusing* the system—they are in the wrong, not you. But you don't really need to make up justifications for why you should be able to delete an answer. You just should.

Comment: @Cody I suspect the OP is just using the wrong definition of serial downvoting. I've seen several heavily downvoted posts where the OP has commented they can't delete them from the app and meanwhile the votes stack up when otherwise they would have deleted it themselves.